# Flash messages doesn't show up cakephp

Tags: cakephp, flash-message

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers are fixing my problem. First of all let me show where I have setFlash and echo $this->Session->flash().

This is my add function:

```
if(!empty($this->request->data))
    {
        $friend_id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
        $user_id = $this->Auth->User('id');
        $already_friends = $this->Group->findByIdAndFriend($user_id, $friend_id);
        if($already_friends)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are already friends', true));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Group->create();
            $data = array($user_id, $friend_id);
            if($this->Group->save($data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are now friends', true));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Failed to add friend. Please try again', true));
            }               
        }
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

This is my layout, the necessary part of it:

```
    <div id="header">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('connect.jpg', array('alt' => 'My Image', 'id' => 'headerImage')) ?>
            <div id="headerNavMenu">
                <div name="navTab" class="menuTab">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Me', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id")), array('class' => 'tabName')) ?>                        
                </div>
                <div name="navTab" class="menuTab">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('My Schedule', array('controller' => 'newSchedules', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'tabName')) ?>
                </div>
                <div name="navTab" class="menuTab">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('My Group', array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'tabName')) ?>
                </div>
                <div name="navTab" class="menuTab">
                    <a href="#" class="tabName">Settings</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="login">
                <?php echo CakeSession::read("Auth.User.firstName").' '.CakeSession::read("Auth.User.lastName").' '  ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link('logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Besides the fact that no flash messages show up, it also seems like the validation criteria is not being checked for models since specific messages don't show up either.

I am new at cakePHP but I have been following the blog tutorial to do most of my work. The flash messages used to work, but now it doesn't work for even models it used to.

Here are my validations:

```
public $validate = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'First Name cannot be blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true
        )
    ),
    'last_name' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Last Name cannot be blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Email cannot be blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true
        ),
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('email', true),          
            'message' => 'This is not a valid email',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'This email already exists',
            'required' => true
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Password cannot be blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true
        ),
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('minlength', 6),
            'message' => 'Password has to be at least 6 characters',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'password_has_to_be_alphanumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphanumeric',
            'message' => 'Password has to be alphanumeric',
            'required' => true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I am inclined to agree with simofox and make sure you are including the session component, However, if your debugging is set to 1 or 2 then you should receive a very helpful error message. Something like, Call to a member function setFlash() on non object. If you don't get this message then something in your appController may be overriding the flash message. Something to try is add a flash message to the top of your controller function above if(!empty) and then under the message type pr($this->Session) and at least search for your target message in the array to narrow down your issues.

Comment: my debugging is set to 2. and weirdly enough some flash messages are showing up. appController does have the session component. However my validation criteria is still not working.

Comment: try to manually check the validation... what do you get?    
$this->Group->set($this->request->data); 
   pr($this->Group->validates())

Comment: i get nothing from the validates

Comment: can we see your validation rules in the model?

Comment: I just added them to my original post

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments so I have to answer, but in line 4 of your add function You should write user in lower case
`$this->Auth->user('id');`.
Theme check to have added Session component to your $components array in AppController

Comment: $this->Auth->User('id') seems to work for the rest of my logic